# Зачем закрывать подключения?

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Разбираюсь с `mysqli`, в частности с этим примером:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* проверка подключения */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        /* выборка данных и помещение их в массив */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
        }

        /* очищаем результирующий набор */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    /* закрываем подключение */
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

И напросился вопрос: зачем нужно очищать результат набора, `mysqli_free_result($result);`, закрывать подключения `mysqli_close($link);` и чем плохо, если этого не делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, откуда предыдущий оратор вообразил какой-то "таймаут".

Соединение с БД закрывать не надо - оно закроется само по окончании работы скрипта. Сразу. БЕЗ каких-либо "таймаутов".

Резалтсет в большинстве случаев очищать не нужно, поскольку как только закончит выполнение вызвавшая его функция, он так же обнулится.

Answer (score 1):

Незакрытые соединения прибьются по таймауту. Но если таких подключений будет очень много, система будет тормозить очень сильно, так как всё это потребляемые ресурсы. Поэтому "уходя, гасите свет".
[mysql_options php.su](http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=mysql_options) и оф. доки [dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html)

Рекомендую для общего развития установить [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) с [*nix системой](http://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/tuning/install_freebsd_4.11/), установить [веб-сервер+mysql](http://www.lissyara.su/?id=2222) и поиграться с настройками, чтобы наглядно увидеть, что и как работает.

mysqli_free_result - очищает используемый блок памяти.

Если простыми словами то - при выполнения кода, к примеру запрос съел 100мб памяти и не была применена команда mysqli_free_result то если дальше по коду есть ещё запросы то они будут ещё дожирать память в дополнение к уже используемой. А если выполним mysqli_free_result то память занятая запросом очистится и мы сможем повторно её использовать в этом же коде.

Если у Вас в выполняемом коде один запрос, то mysqli_free_result необязателен, так как при завершении выполнении кода память всё равно очистится, но если по коду будет множество запросов то лучше очищать используемую память.

Пример 1:

```
php-код
1 sql-запрос # использовал 10мб памяти
php-код
2  sql-запрос # использовал 5мб памяти
```

В итоге получается что для выполнения кода потребовалось 15мб памяти, так как используемую память мы не очищали и она содержала первый запрос.

Пример 2:

```
php-код
1 sql-запрос # использовал 10мб памяти
mysqli_free_result (очищает уже задействованные 10мб памяти в которые можно записать последующие запросы)
php-код
2  sql-запрос # использовал 5мб памяти
```

Для выполнения кода потребовалось 10мб памяти, так как мы очистили память от первого запроса и записали в неё второй.

Comment: Честно, полностью поддерживаю идею VirtualBox, но пока что нужно победить лень.

Comment: Лень это недостаток интереса к делу.

Comment: А зачем нужно очищать результат набора mysqli_free_result($result) ?

Comment: дополнил ответ

Comment: Не понял, где это соединение останется висеть-то? Вот отработал процесс php, создавший соединение и закрылся. Где память? А если остаётся где-то, можно ли его повторно использовать?

Comment: в памяти, которую использует запущенный код. Дополнил ответ примерами.

Comment: Спасибо, так понятнее. А есть тесты, подтверждающие эту арифметику? Т.к., напр., `unset()` объекта ещё не гарантирует, что [gc](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.php), если он вообще включён в php.ini, соберёт и переиспользует освобождённую память.

Comment: в Unix запускал php как cgi ( для отслеживания от какого пользователя скрипт запущен) и по команде top отслеживал потребление памяти на больших запросах.