# Закрытие соединений

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Вопрос в дополнение к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383770/php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Суть такова. Есть вот такой код:

```
$result_id_position = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id_position FROM category_position WHERE id_category = '$_GET[category]'");
$id_position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_id_position);

        if (empty($id_position[0])) {
            $positions = "null";
        } else {
            $positions = array();
            do {
                $result_position = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM positions WHERE id = '$id_position[0]'");
                $position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_position);

                $positions[$position[0]] = array(
                    "title" => $position[1],
                    "class" => $position[0] == $_GET['position'] ? "active" : "",
                    "amount" => mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM goods WHERE id_position='$position[id]' "))[0]
                );

            } while ($id_position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_id_position));
            $result_position->close();
        }
        $result_id_position->close();
```

Вопросы следующие:
 1. Насколько сильно данный код грузит сервер, ведь здесь в цикле есть запрос, и можно ли этот код как-то оптимизировать?
 2. В цикле есть запрос, который как бы не присваивался никакой переменной `"amount" => mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM goods WHERE id_position='$position[id]' "))[0]`, нужно ли его закрывать?
 3. Нужно ли в конце писать `mysqli_close($db);`, если да, то зачем?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> Насколько сильно данный код грузит сервер, ведь здесь в цикле есть запрос

На этот вопрос ответить невозможно. Это хуже, чем если бы данные грузились одним запросом, но не факт, что этот один запрос не "весил" бы больше текущего куска кода, но скорее всего это настолько микроскопические операции, что наплевать.
И вообще, в каких единицах измерять нагрузку? У вас тормозит именно в этом месте? Вы собираетесь начать оптимизировать возможно оптимально выполняющееся место до того, как начали разбираться в алгоритмической сложности написанного кода?

> можно ли этот код как то оптимизировать ?

Да.

1. Выучить [оператор](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) [JOIN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))
2. Выучить условие [IN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)
3. Никогда не пихать в запрос данные напрямую из POST / GET
4. Перейти на [PDO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/), хотя бы ради читаемости

> В цикле есть запрос который как бы не присваивался никакой переменной

Как бы не присваивается? Это как? Он вполне себе присваивается элементу `amount` массива, который, в свою очередь, является элементом массива `$positions`.

> нужно ли его закрывать?

Как вы собрались закрыть (!) запрос?

> Нужно ли в конце писать `mysqli_close($db);`, если да, то зачем ?

Если очень грубо, то да, если это является последним обращением к базе данных. Проще вынести завершение подключения в `register_shutdown_function()`. Потому что при работе напрямую с ресурсами подчищать за собой является хорошим тоном. Завтра будете переносить код на очередной комплируемый порт PHP, а там утечка вылезет.