# Рекомендуете ли вы чистить память от результата запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Что скажете по этому поводу, до этого я не чистил память.
В офф. документации сказано:

> Замечание: Нужно всегда очищать память функцией mysqli_free_result(),
>   если результаты запроса больше не нужны.

Хочу послушать ваше мнение.

Comment: А что дальше с переменной результатом происходит ? По идее если она остается в живых то ресурсы остаются заняты. Но если выйдет из области видимости или будет использована для следующего запроса сборщик мусора должен вызвать все деструкторы

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383770/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F